# Image Upload HTTP 500 Internal server error

Tags: images, 500-internal-error

While I upload images the images are uploaded in the uploads folder but dont get response rather it get a HTTP error(500 Internal server error).

I have tried all the solutions to fix the upload image.Turned off the mod_security from the htaccess.Increased the memory size.Also changed the permalink to default previously it was postname.I have also tried with both the flash uploader & the browser uploader.And get the error in the async-upload.php.

Comment: Did you checked the server log? What is the detail of the error?

Comment: I have checked the server log it just show a small php warning nothing much.Its working fine in my localhost.I have a windows server with the apache installed

Comment: @khadkaboy did you resolve this?

Comment: Another question might be related to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/172115/103228